# obj.attr('id') return undefined but obj.getAttribute('id') works. Why?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, attr, getattribute

In my JS obj.attr('...') and obj.prop('...') doesn't work but obj.getAttribute('...') works well.

Could you guys tell me why?

```
function ShowTips(obj) // show tip in element's attribute
{
    var msg = obj.attr("tip"); // failed. 
    alert(msg);
}

function startPoint() // start from here.
{
    var obj = document.getElementById("img01");
    ShowTips(obj);
}
```

Comment: wrap obj with jQuery `$(obj)` to use jQuery functions.

Answer (score 5):

*obj* is a DOM element, not a jQuery object. Wrap *obj* in $() to objectify it:

`$(obj).attr("tip")`;

Answer (score 1):

create `obj` as jquery object.

```
var obj = $("#img01");
ShowTips(obj);
```